# Operator Norm of $ 3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find the operator norm $\|A\|_o = \sup \|Ax\|_2$, the supremum being taken over all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\|x\|_2 = 1$. Here $A$ is the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1\\ 1&0&1 \\ 1&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
and $||.||_2$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Please could someone help me? Do I just need to find the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$ ?

If so, I have found the eigenvalues of the above to be $1$ and $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Your operator is symmetric, meaning that it's diagonalizable by an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors (two corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$, and one to $2$). If we let those be $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ then one has $\|A(\sum_{j=1}^3\alpha_j e_j)\|_2^2 = 1^2(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2) + 4\alpha_3^2$, where $\|\sum_{j=1}^3\alpha_j e_j\|_2^2 = \alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2$. It follows (and you could do the same with every normal operator) that $\|A\|_o=2$.

If $A$ isn't normal, $A^TA$ is, and if its maximal (absolute value) eigenvalue is $\alpha$, then the same process gives us $\|Ax\|_2^2 = |x^TA^TAx|\leq \|x^T\|_2\|A^TAx\|_2\leq \|x^T\|_2 |\alpha|\|x\|_2 = |\alpha|\|x\|_2^2$, and it is reachable with an eigenvector belonging to $\alpha$, implying that $\|A\|_o =\sqrt{|\alpha|}$.